# Unscramble effect in jQuery while maintaining the format

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins, text

I'm using the unscramble plugin from [Jason Frame's Grab Bag](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html).

But it seems only to work with text that has no format. I want that the text formatting remains unchanged.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/G6BdX/

The unscramble plugin:

```
    $.fn.unscramble = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), replace = /[^\s]/,
                state = [], choose = [], reveal = 25, random = randomAlphaNum;

            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (str[i].match(replace)) {
                    state.push(random());
                    choose.push(i);
                } else {
                    state.push(str[i]);
                }
            }

            shuffle(choose);
            $ele.text(state.join(''));

            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                var i, r = reveal;
                while (r-- && choose.length) {
                    i = choose.pop();
                    state[i] = str[i];
                }
                for (i = 0; i < choose.length; i++) state[choose[i]] = random();
                $ele.text(state.join(''));
                if (choose.length == 0) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    };
```

As you can see when pressed 'Unscramble me' the text format and the <*br*> tags are removed.

Due to my lack of skills in making jQuery plug-ins, I don't know what the problem is. I think it goes wrong when replacing */[^\s]/* but I'm not sure.

Somebody has an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation *says* it only works on unformatted text. There's nothing broken here. What you want is a whole new plugin.

Comment: Rewrite the plugin to work with elements other than pure text.